# How can I avoid duplicate values in a single column when combining multiple Excel files using Python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, sorting, duplicates

How to avoid duplication of values

Hellow guys, i have a problem. I just got started with python to try to automate some reports from my job. The thing is that  i have 18-20 reports each one from a  different month, but is the same kind of report. I want to  join al these excel file into a single(which i already did) and one of the colmuns is "invoice", and sometimes they put the same invoice let's say in the June report when that invoice alrady was in the January report. I just want to know  the code so i can't just stay with one. The thing is that each report is  like 1000-20000 rows, so if i have a few invoices repeated, it is actually a lot. Hope someone could help, have a great day!!

Comment: As you work through the spreadsheets maintain a set of invoice numbers. You can check the contents of the set to avoid duplication

Comment: How are you joining these files?  If you're gathering them all into a single list, then you can certainly search the list to find duplications.

Comment: Or if you're using pandas to combine them, then `drop_duplicates`. But we really need to see *how* you're combining here.

Comment: I suppose your rows contain more data than just an invoice.  When there is a duplicate invoice, can you rely on all the other columns to be the same, as well?  My guess would be that that's probably not a safe assumption.  Have you considered, then, how to handle such conflicts?  And if they are genuinely conflicts, then have you considered whether it's even correct to drop any of the rows?